# Use shared variable in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

Hi I am using BLAS to do some math computation in Spark.I got 2 `JavaPairRDDs` that both has a **Double[]**  field, I want to caculate dot product as follow:

```
userPairRDD.cartesian(itemPairRDD).mapToPair(
                    new PairFunction<Tuple2<Tuple2<String, Double[]>, Tuple2<String, Double[]>>, String, ItemAndWeight>() {
                        @Override
                        public Tuple2<String, ItemAndWeight> call(Tuple2<Tuple2<String, Double[]>, Tuple2<String, Double[]>> tuple2Tuple2Tuple2) throws Exception {
                            BLAS.getInstance().ddot("......");
                            .......
                        }
                    }
            )
```

My question is, in my **call()**,I called **BLAS.getInstance()** every time it might be inefficient, Can I create only one BLAS object outside `call(`) and just the very object to do ddot()?
Is there any point to take care as this is a distributed program? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For shared variables look into broadcast variables to actually share some data between worker nodes. For shared resources i.e. database connections use map partitions and create /use one resource per partition, i.e. in your case use `BLAS.getInstance` once per partition.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need shared variable in this case. `BLAS.getInstance()` just return a static/singleton instance, so no inefficient thing here.